# Access host database from service located in a docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

If I have a Postgres database running on the host machine (os: Linux), and some service running in a container of docker-compose. How would I access the database from service in a container? How .yaml file of the service in docker-compose should look like?

Answer (score 1):

Using recent (20.10 or later) versions of Docker on Linux, you can configure a host alias using the `host-gateway` target, like this:

```
docker run -it --rm --add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway alpine
```

Or in your `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
version: "3"

services:
  myservice:
    image: myimage
    extra_hosts:
      - host.docker.internal:host-gateway
```

With this configuration, you can refer to your hostas `host.docker.internal` (support for this was added in https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/40007). Support for the `host.docker.internal` alias has been available under MacOS and Windows for a while (where the network configuration made it more of a necessity).

For example:

```
host$ docker run -it --rm --add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway alpine sh
/ # ping -c1 host.docker.internal
PING host.docker.internal (172.17.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.17.0.1: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.049 ms

--- host.docker.internal ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.049/0.049/0.049 ms
/ #
```

You're not required to use the name `host.docker.internal`; you could just as easily run:

```
host$ docker run -it --rm --add-host bobs.yer.uncle:host-gateway alpine sh
/ # ping -c1 bobs.yer.uncle
PING bobs.yer.uncle (172.17.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.17.0.1: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.116 ms

--- bobs.yer.uncle ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.116/0.116/0.116 ms
/ #
```

But the name `host.docker.internal` shows up various bits of documentation so it makes a good choice.

---

Prior to Docker 20.10, I would have said:

On Linux, the host can be reached at any of it's non-`localhost` addresses. A convenient target is the address of the Docker bridge to which your container is connected (`docker0` when using the default network, or the one created dynamically for other Docker networks).

So if your system has an interface configuration like this:

```
[...]
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:aa:fa:77 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp1s0
    inet 192.168.123.106/24 brd 192.168.123.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft 2648sec preferred_lft 2648sec
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:feaa:fa77/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: docker_gwbridge: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:3d:cf:c5:af brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.23.0.1/16 brd 172.23.255.255 scope global docker_gwbridge
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:3dff:fecf:c5af/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:51:75:28:24 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:51ff:fe75:2824/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
[...]
```

You could use either 192.168.123.106, 172.23.0.1, or 172.17.0.1 as the
address of your host.

From inside a container, you can get the address of the associated bridge by looking up the default gateway:

```
$ ip route | awk '$1 == "default" {print $3}'
172.17.0.1
```

Otherwise, just pick a host address and use it. Note that if you're running with a restrictive firewall configuration you may need to open the necessary ports to permit the access.

---

NB:

- You cannot assume the address of the `docker0` bridge will
  be `172.17.0.1`: depending on your local network configuration, Docker
  may choose a different network range for that bridge (so, just check
  first).
- If you are running with a restrictive firewall configuration, you
  may need to open up the necessary ports in order for containers to
  access services on your host.

Answer (score -1):

On Linux, the host can be reached at 172.17.0.1.

You usually don't change anything in your docker-compose file. You change the settings in your program where you tell it the address of the database server.