# Docker Containers and Separate Database

Tags: docker, mariadb

I have a Ubuntu server and I have Mariadb installed locally as I plan to run multiple instances which will need its own separate db and running 30 or so different database containers seem kinda useless.

However, when I do so, My containers can't find 'localhost' as the database hostname. I also tried entering my local IP (192.168.0.xxx) with no luck Do things change when I try to input db details to docker container? What do I need to do to make it work?

update: I created my docker container by pasting the docker compose templates then editing the necessary details like ports, volumes etc. I do this through portainer.

I haven't done anything to connect the container host with the server host as I don't know how to and probably the main reason this isn't working.

update 2: tried method mentioned by Hans Kilian

Here's a temporary Wordpress dockercompose file I created
[image: Here's a temporary Wordpress dockercompose file I created]

and this is my Wordpress database details: [image]

It still refuses connection

Comment: As you haven't shared how you've configured your containers, it's impossible to provide help. I would assume that your database container is not configured to listen on localhost?

Comment: I tried searching for "*docker access host*" and found so many answers here already, did you try those answers? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324981/how-to-access-host-port-from-docker-container, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70006997/access-host-from-within-a-docker-container, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72140321/access-host-database-from-service-located-in-a-docker-container ...

Comment: Sorry I have updated some details so it might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

To access services on the host, you need to add the gateway (the gateway is the host machine) as a known host. You do that by adding `--add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway` to your `docker run` command, like this

```
docker run -d --add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway <myimage>
```

Then, from inside the container, you can access the host by using the hostname `host.docker.internal` instead of `localhost`.

If you use docker-compose, you can add the hostname by adding

```
extra_hosts:
  - host.docker.internal:host-gateway
```

to the service definition instead.

Comment: So If I understand you correctly. I have a docker container named nextcloud so I should do docker run -d --add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway nextcloud?

Sorry I mostly use dockercompose file and portainer to create my instances so not familiar with docker run

Comment: Yes. And change the hostname of the database from `localhost` to `host.docker.internal` in the container

Comment: What if I have the instance running already? docker run doesn't work on existing containers...

Comment: That's true. You have to stop the container first. btw., I updated the answer to include the docker-compose way of adding the host

Comment: hmm, just tried it out. It still says connection refused. :/

Comment: updated the main post with detailed images.